# Bootstrap collapse with checkbox loses sync with its target

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap collapse to show an element when a checkbox is flagged.

This is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" />
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    Checked!
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6sjcqmqx/

**Please try to check quickly many odd times that checkbox**, you will find that it loses sync with its target and then the target is shown when the checkbox is not checked.
I thought that it was related to collapse transition, but also removing collapsing transition this error occours.

How to avoid this using bootstrap collapse by html attributes?

Answer (score 0):

you should do the collapse programmatically, and for the input tag use the `onchange` event to get accurate results. here's the solution https://jsfiddle.net/uLhju7es/2/